# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'FlutterMobileVisionPlugin.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, xcode, google-mlkit

So, here is my pubspec.yaml file:

[image]

And this is the image of the error.

[image]

I've tried Flutter clean, deleting and reinstalling pods. It's just not working.